# Automatic push button in webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to automate some process. 
During the execution of the process opens a webview with a button - "OK", is it possible to press it automatically by software, not touching your finge ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it manually. Work which you want to do, will do programatically and will show to user that button as pressed by code.

Comment: Ok, and how to push button in webview programmatically?

Comment: Use timer for few millisecond to show pressed color on button.

Comment: sorry, you understood it uncorrectly. I mean that button is in html code and I need from android code push button in html. I already handled it by using javascript injection to webview.